# PayPal IPN parameters contain two status fields. Which should I use?

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using the PayPal Adaptive Payments API. I have a script that receives the IPN postback when a payment is made. In this script I need to perform validation, including checking that the status of the payment is `COMPLETED`, [as specified by the documentation](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside):

> Confirm that the "payment_status" is "Completed," since IPNs are also sent for other results such as "Pending" or "Failed"

The documentation hasn't been updated for Adaptive Payments which use different parameters (not `payment_status`). [The parameters I receive are documented here](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIPN) and there are *two* status fields:

> **status**
> The status of the payment. Possible values are:
>
> CREATED – The payment request was received; funds will be transferred once the payment is approved
> COMPLETED – The payment was successful
> INCOMPLETE – Some transfers succeeded and some failed for a parallel payment or, for a delayed chained payment, secondary receivers have not been paid
> ERROR – The payment failed and all attempted transfers failed or all completed transfers were successfully reversed
> REVERSALERROR – One or more transfers failed when attempting to reverse a payment
> PROCESSING – The payment is in progress
> PENDING – The payment is awaiting processing

and

> **transaction[n].status**
> The transaction status, where [n] is a number from 0 to 5. For simple single-receiver payments, this number will be 0. Numbers larger than 0 indicate the payment to a particular receiver in chained and parallel payments.
>
> Possible values are:
>
> Completed
> Pending
> Refunded

Simply put, I don't know which one I should be using. The *payment status* or the *transaction status*?

(I'd place my bets on transaction status but then I don't know what the purpose of the payment status is when you have more than one transaction in a request (when using chained payments, for example). Then again, the payment status has more possible values, so perhaps that's the "overall" status and should be used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to look at transaction[n].status, and this would be an array.  This is because with adaptive payments, a single transaction can be split into multiple transactions to different merchants.

The status is just saying that the api call went through and completed successfully.  It was processed.  The transaction[n].status tells you what the status is of each transaction in that call.

Comment: This makes sense, but do you have a source? Any documentation anywhere that mentions it? ... or even _how_ you came to this conclusion?

Comment: I don't think any of the public docs clearly explain this.  This is the intended functionality, and should be what you see if you use IPN with with Adaptive Payments.  I have also seen this from my own personal testing in the past, and from other merchants that have reported the same results and asked the same questions.

Comment: Okay, thanks. As long as no one else comes along to challenge you, I'll mark this as accepted answer.